# Magento 2 Oauth request token - oauth_problem=Invalid+signature

Tags: api, magento2.2, oauth

Magento 2 Oauth error invalid signature while try to get request token from postman

[image]

Comment: I think your post URL is wrong.  try this 

http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token

Comment: I am using oauth credentials to authenticate the application

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Not yet........

Comment: in postman uncheck "encode signature" option.

Answer (score 2):

If you supply all of those values, you don't have to use the access or request routes. postman will take care of the rest.

[image]

Typically I've noticed that some routes are slightly different; ie.

use:
http://***your url here***/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria=

instead of:
http://***your url here***/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria

Notice the difference with the **=**

The only time you need to use those routes are when you post to your callback and identity urls.